# Shower leak at the corner of my shower pan where it joins the shower surround. Best solution - Remove drywall and caulk the exterior?

Tags: shower, leak

I've got a small leak outside my shower causing drywall damage. Recaulked inside already, but wetness persists. Suspecting slow drainage via weep holes, and water is dripping via the failing exterior caulk.

Tips on stopping the leak as a stop-gap without removing drywall?

Exterior where the leak is

[image]

Corresponding spot on the showerbase

[image]

Comment: How desperate are you? Once the drywall is, indeed, dry, you could get yourself a tube of [Through the Roof](https://www.amazon.com/Sashco-Through-Sealant-Ounce-Cartridge/dp/B00IQCIE0C) sealant. It's usually used for sealing things on your roof, so it'll definitely seal the drywall... but is the water leaking from "outside" the drywall (inside the room) or is it leaking "inside" the drywall (inside the wall)? Knowing the path the water takes is important or we'll just make the problem worse.

Comment: Sounds like I have to cut open the drywall then. Eyeballing this, it looks like it is leaking from the exterior caulking seam. But I have no clear way to tell if the source of the leak is higher up behind the drywall.

I plan to replace the drywall _eventually_ anyway, since that 2"x2" drywall is now soggy. I am wishful in that I can 2-step it with (1) stopping the leak (2) replace the drywall later.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the water is inside the shower.  The caulking must be done inside first.

The common issue is the bottom corner where the glass frame meets the shower base and walls, as well as the joint between the base and wall. Also check the entire length of the glass frame. Water is weeping and can come from the tiniest of openings.

Clean out any old caulk and debris. re-caulk with silicone inside.

Use the shower for a few days.  If the leak is repaired, you can caulk the exterior between the wall and shower base with latex caulk.

Comment: I recaulked the inside of the shower a few weeks back. I made sure that inside corner is rock solid. I did leave space between the glass and frame since it has its own weep holes that drain back into the shower pan.


Q1: Sounds like I *should* caulk the seams along the entire length of the glass frame. Is this right?


Q2: Is there specific reason the exterior side should be latex caulk vs. silicone caulk?

Comment: @slice, Latex caulk is paintable. Lay some caulk down. Wipe it with a sponge. Touch up the paint. Done.  You can't do that with silicone.

Comment: Roger that. Thank you @RMDman